# Exception in commit tran in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, exception, transactions, commit

I have a problem when using hibernate.

```
for Loop
  begin tran
  select record
  insert record
  commit tran
  if exception, rollback tran
end
```

In first occurrence, I insert a record with invalid foreign key value, then throw exception when commit the transaction.
In second occurrence, either I select record or insert correct record, it throw exception, the exception belongs to the second occurrence.

As each occurrence in the for loop have no dependency, therefore, I want to commit for those correct record, and just rollback for those invalid record. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
for (...) {
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        s.beginTransaction();
        // do work...
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if ( ! s.getTransaction().isActive())
            try { s.getTransaction().rollback(); }
            catch (Exception ignored) {
                log.warn("Ignored rollback error", ignored); 
            }
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The [Session's javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) says:

> If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
>   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
>   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

Creating the session is cheap, just be sure to have connection pool configured correctly. If your work-unit is very small, it might be worth to test the scenario, that you will open new session only after exception, otherwise just [`clear()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29) it.